# Using Firebase Firestore Database User Reference

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, profile

I have been reading about firestore and I am implementing it into my app.

The code that I was reading uses a realtime database and I am using cloud firestore database. The code I found is:

```
let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/profile/\(uid)")
userRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
```

How can I get this in firestore instead of realtime databse

Thanks

Comment: It would help us to help you if we understood what you were trying to do with that code. Are you trying to read a particular node that contains information about the user? Typically the structure would be */users/uid* but you've got */users/profile/uid* so maybe you are doing something different?

Answer (score 1):

There is no 1:1 translation of the code between the two APIs. You will have to read the documentation of both, and rewrite them yourself.

To be able to read user profiles from Cloud Firestore you must already be storing user profiles in Cloud Firestore. If you `observe` a node in the Firebase Realtime Database, your closure gets called with both the current data and upon any updates to that that. The equivalent in Firestore is attaching a realtime listener as shown here:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen